# Why is PdfPTable not visible in Paragraph if keepTogether is set to true?

Tags: java, itext, openpdf

I'm using *OpenPdf 1.3.8* (fork of *itext*) and *openjdk 1.8.0_192*.

I'm trying to group table with two texts (one above, and one below table) to prevent splitting of elements when they don't fit in remaining empty space on page.

Elements are added to *Paragraph* with *keepTogether* set to true. I noticed peculiar behavior when using *setKeepTogether(true)*.

If *setKeepTogether(true)* is called, table won't appear, other elements will:

[image]

If setKeepTogether(false) - everything works as expected:

[image]

Here is my code example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, FileNotFoundException {
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(DEST));
  document.open();
  
  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
  table.addCell("Lorem");
  table.addCell("ipsum");
  table.addCell("dolor");
  table.addCell("sit");
  
  Paragraph mainParagraph = new Paragraph();
  Paragraph paragraph1 = new Paragraph("Text above table");
  Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph("Text below table");
  
  mainParagraph.add(paragraph1);
  mainParagraph.add(table);
  mainParagraph.add(paragraph2);
  
  // if keeptogether is true, table is not visible
  mainParagraph.setKeepTogether(true);
  
  document.add(mainParagraph);
  
  document.close();}
```

Any clue as to what is happening?

Code is also tested with *itext 5.5.13*. With *itext* in both cases table is visible.

Comment: In the end I posted the same question on project [github](https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF/issues/271). It turned out to be a bug and since version 1.3.12 the bug has been fixed.